# How to extract information from related HTML tags using BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to code an app that uses information from a HTML file to work.

The (relevant) structure of the HTML file is something like this:

```py
</div>
    <div class="BEANS">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/> Subdir Name (<b>Root Dir Name</b>)
    </div>

    <div class="SAUSAGES">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/> 
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download/0001">Filetype 1</a> | 
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download-alt/0001">Filetype 2</a>
        178.2kB
    </div>

   <div class="BEANS">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/> Subdir Name (<b>Root Dir Name</b>)
    </div>

    <div class="SAUSAGES">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/> 
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download/0002">Another Filetype 1</a> | 
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download-alt/0002">Another Filetype 2</a>
        248.1kB
    </div>
[this exact format repeated about 20 times, each with a BEANS div and SAUSAGES DIV]
</div>
```

As visible, this is all wrapped up in one big `<div>` with no class or identifier. It alternates betweens a BEANS div and a SAUSAGES div until the unlabeled DIV is finally closed.

I am trying to use BS4 to traverse this format after getting it with `requests.get(url.com).content`, and the desired outcome is to download each file with the directory format of "C:/Root Dir Name/Subdir Name/Filetype 1.file" and "C:/Root Dir Name/Subdir Name/Filetype 2.file". As visible, the RootDir and SubDir names can be extracted from BEANS, but the actual file itself must be downloaded from the relevant SAUSAGES div just below it.

My problem is that I'm unsure how to ensure that the BEANS matches to the relevant SAUSAGES. I could iterate through the no-class main div that contains them, but even then I'm not sure how to make BEANS correspond to SAUSAGES. The actual downloading mechanism isn't very important to this question, more a method of traversing this tree. Maybe I'm being dumb but I'm confused about this as BEANS and SAUSAGES aren't each held in a div, they're *all* in one big div.

Any ideas?

I've tried iterating through `requests.get(url.com).content` with a .find()/.find_all() but I'm unsure how to utilise it in this context.

I have seen similar questions on SO, however the issue is the format that this uses. I'm unsure how to make sure each SAUSAGES corresponds to BEANS, and the next time it comes across a pair in the main div, create a new RootDir and SubDir for that pair.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to match every `HYPERLINK` to it's `BEANS` (subdirectory):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<div>
    <div class="BEANS">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/> Subdir Name 1 (<b>Root Dir Name 1</b>)
    </div>

    <div class="SAUSAGES">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/>
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download/0001">Filetype 1</a> |
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download-alt/0001">Filetype 2</a>
        178.2kB
    </div>

   <div class="BEANS">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/> Subdir Name 2 (<b>Root Dir Name 2</b>)
    </div>

    <div class="SAUSAGES">
        <img alt="." class="icon_img" src="/image.gif"/>
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download/0002">Another Filetype 1</a> |
        <a class="HYPERLINK" href="download-alt/0002">Another Filetype 2</a>
        248.1kB
    </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a.HYPERLINK'):
    tmp = a.find_previous(class_='BEANS')
    rootdir, subdir = tmp.b.text, tmp.get_text(strip=True).split('(')[0].strip()
    print(rootdir, '|', subdir, '|', a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
Root Dir Name 1 | Subdir Name 1 | download/0001
Root Dir Name 1 | Subdir Name 1 | download-alt/0001
Root Dir Name 2 | Subdir Name 2 | download/0002
Root Dir Name 2 | Subdir Name 2 | download-alt/0002
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to a (rather poorly asked, lol) question - I think this will work :)